# Windows 7 QueryPerformanceFrequency returns 2.4 MHz-ish?

Tags: windows, performancecounter

I'm running some timing code on various OS.  I notice the following patterns with the results from QueryPerformanceCounter

Standard Windows XP uses the processor frequency, which means it's using RDTSC under the hood.

Vista uses the HPET, 14,318,180 Hz

Any version of Windows with /usepmtimer uses the ACPI clock, 3,579,545 Hz

Windows 7 uses a clock of undetermined origin, returning varying numbers around 2.4 to 2.6 MHz.

Does anyone know what clock Windows 7 is using by default?  Why is it even slower than the ACPI clock?  Is there a way to force Windows 7 to use the HPET instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 will pick different QPC sources at boot based on what processor / hardware is available - I believe there are also changes in SP1 regarding this as well.

The change from Vista was most likely taken for AppCompat reasons, since on multicore CPUs that are reading RDTSC, they are not guaranteed to be in-sync, so apps being scheduled on multiple CPUs would sometimes see QPC go backwards and would freak out.

Comment: Yeah, Vista uses HPET to overcome multiple issues with RDTSC.  I'm still curious what clock Windows 7 is using, and why MS went from HPET = 14 MHz-ish to ??? = 2.4 MHz-ish.

Answer (score 3):

Ok this is only a partial answer as I'm still nailing it down, but this 2.x MHz frequency is equal to the nominal TSC speed divided by 1024.

Try to do the math with your QPF result and your own CPU speed and it should be right.

I initially thought it was a division of the HPET rate but it does not seem to be the case.

Now the question is: the LAPIC timer runs at system bus rate but so is the TSC (before the mult coeff is applied) so we don't know what counter is used before the final division (it could be TSC/1024 or BUS/something else) but we know it's using the main motherboard crystal (the one driving the bus)

What doesn't sound right is that some MSDN articles seem to imply the LAPIC timer is barely used (excepted for hypervisor/virtual machines) but given the fact that the HPET failed to deliver its promises due to many implementation problems, and the fact most new platforms feature an invariant TSC, they are changing direction again.

I didn't found any formal proof from Microsoft concerning the new source used in Win7 though... and we can't completely rule the HPET as even if it's not used in timer mode its counters can still be read (ex: by QPF) but why divide its rate and thus lower its resolution then?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please keep me informed on your progress!  I believe I have seen QPF return different results on the same machine day-after-day.  Also according to this Steam Forum post http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=22501783&postcount=115 W7 appears to use a hybrid TSC/(LAPIC|HPET) combination for QPC, depending on various parameters.  According to that post, typing "bcdedit /set useplatformclock true" into cmd prompt, reboot, enable HPET in BIOS, and you should be able to use pure HPET.

Comment: Yes I read that article but it's full of inaccuracies! The author keeps mixing ACPI PMT and LAPIC which are completely different things (and the LAPIC can not emulate the PMT) and some of his claims are clearly dubious... Meanwhile I kept searching and searching but didn't find any explanation of that 1024 division. I'll keep you informed whenever I make any progress.

Comment: By the way, just to be sure, are you on a Intel Core i3/5/7 platform?

Comment: Alright this is for FreeBSD but so far it's the closest explanation to the behaviour we see: http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?2670271-svn+commit%3A+r222866+-+head%2Fsys%2Fx86%2Fx86 ---- the idea is to discard the lowest bits of the TSC (in Win7 that would be the 10 LSB to yield a 1024 division) this way by reducing the accuracy they are able to mask some of the possible problems encountered when using the TSC on a SMP machine, even when it's reported as invariant.

Comment: Our software should run on a variety of platforms so we can't really specify Intel Core processors.  However, I am personally interested in forcing W7 to use pure HPET with no TSC, which should be a perfect 14,318,180 Hz.  I do, however, thank you for that nice link on FreeBSD, it certainly explains very well the default behavior of the W7 QPC.

Comment: I stepped through a call to QueryPerformanceCounter at assembly level on Windows 7, and found that the TSC (as obtained by `rdtsc`) is explicitly divided by 1024.  Not sure why they do this.